# Can mapkit framework provided in iphone be used to create an enterprise application?

Tags: iphone, google-maps

Can mapkit framework provided in iphone be used to create an enterprise application, without violating Google privacy and terms. As I am creating enterprise application using enterprise certificate (http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/) form apple, wanted to know weather I can use makkit framework in my application application for distribution within the enterprise and on itunes app store.

Please let me know if there is any additional legal agreement/certificates involved.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of apps do. I guess it's an assumption on my part, but I've assumed that the presence of MapKit in the API implies that whatever licensing issues might have been there have been taken care of already.

Comment: But the content covered in http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html looks confusing for terms and condition for using mapkit framework. Ref from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html